# npm 'sass' package compile empty file in watch mode

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I use the npm `sass` library to compile my ".scss" file and it works really well without any problem but in watch mode, after some file save it starts to produce an empty file. I restart the app and it compiles successfully again.
my watch file is at this link:
[sass builder file](https://github.com/javadbat/hybrid-boilerplate/blob/facc838593f931b9483cb8bd3d1cbf35d7866541/Command/Build/SassBuilder.js)
I don't know if this is my watcher problem or sass problem or even windows file system problem.
can anyone check to help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try many ways to fix this issue and I found the problem is the Windows file system.
in the windows file system if I save a file for a short moment depend on your system performance the file get empty and refill again so to fix this issue I add the `setTimeout` function in watch mode about 500ms so when user save scss file and we detect change first we wait 500ms then execute build function.

```js
//before
 if (fileName && event == "change") {
   this.buildSassFile(fileConfig);            
 }
//after
 if (fileName && event == "change") {
   setTimeout(()=>{
     this.buildSassFile(fileConfig);
   },300);
                
 }
```